# ULPs calculation in Goldberg paper

Tags: floating-point

I've been reading the paper *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*.

I have seen various ULP calculations and felt I pretty much understood it until the discussion of subtraction came up.

```
Take another example: 10.1 - 9.93. This 
becomes 
x = 1.01 × 10^1

y = 0.99 × 10^1 
x - y = .02 × 10^1


The correct answer is .17, so the computed difference is off by 30 ulps 
and is wrong in every digit!
```

Why is this 30ulps and not 0.3? Because surely the ulp is 0.01x10^1, or in other words 0.1. The error is 0.03, which is 0.3 ulps.

Comment: The error is 0.03, which is 30 * 0.001, (where 0.001 is the ULP when p=3 and the value is 0.2).

Comment: So to be certain here - is the value of the ULP always dependent on the lowest possible exponent that can be used to represent a floating point number even if the numbers in the calculation up to that point had higher exponents?

Comment: Basically, yes.  Remember that most floating-point systems insist on a normalized/canonical representation of each value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ULP is not "when". It is a function of one parameter. ULP of WHAT here is 0.001, please?

Comment: @Gangnus: The absolute value of the ULP is a function of the number of significant digits, and the absolute value of the number being represented, surely?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "The absolute value of the ULP is a function of the number of significant digits"- no. "...value of the ULP is a function of the number of significant digits, and the absolute value of the number being represented"- yes. Without the first "absolute"

Comment: In computer science and numerical analysis, unit in the last place or unit of least precision (ULP) is the spacing between floating-point numbers, i.e., the value the least significant digit represents if it is 1. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, what about:  In general, if the floating-point number d.d...d × B^e is used to represent z, then it is in error by |d.d...d - (z/B^e)|B^(p-1) units in the last place. 0.02*10^1 is used to represent 0.17, so it is in error by |0.02-(0.17/10^1)|*10^(2) = 0.3 ulps

Comment: I also have the same question. Have you figured out why it's 30?

Comment: Lol ran into exactly this problem. It's doubly confusing because earlier he mentions they're going to ignore subnormals initially, so I assumed we weren't normalizing :p

Comment: compare them in normalized representations 1.70 and 2.00, there is difference of 30 units in last place. So, 30ulps.

Comment: Thanks, so this conforms it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is written in the comments but I'll write it down as an answer so that it's not hidden in the comment noise.

Basically `x - y = .02 × 10^1` gets normalized to `2.00 × 10^-1`, and this means that the ULP is now the smallest value in this normalized representation: `0.01 × 10^-1`.

Consequently the error is

```
0.03 / [(0.01 × 10^-1)/ULP] = 30 ULP
```

Answer (score 0):

> the ULP is now the smallest value in this normalized representation: 0.01 × 10^-1.

What some answers don't highlight, is that **ULP is relative to the approximated value**.

It is not the smallest representable number, but the difference between best lower and upper approximations of the given number.

Let me rework this example in two ways:

a)

The exact result of `.17` satisfies these optimal, within precision of 3, bounds:

```
0.01 x 10^1 <= .17 <= 0.02 x 10^1
```

hence the ULP equals

```
ULP(0.17) = 0.02 x 10^1 - 0.01 x 10^1 = 0.01 x 10^1 = 0.1
```

and consequently, the error is

```
0.02x10^1-0.17 = 0.03 = 30 ULP
```

b)

You can also use this fact from the paper

> In general, if the floating-point number d.d...d × 10^e is used to represent z, then it is in error by |d.d...d - (z/10^e)| x 10^(p-1) units in the last place

Since we approximate `0.17=1.7x10^-1` with `0.2=2x10^-1`
the result gives us

```
|1.7-2|x10^2 ULP = 30 ULP.
```

NOTE: Usually, we abbreviate `ULP(x)` to `ULP` for the sake of brevity.